# Querying a column that shows [count] of [max count]

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

**I have 3 tables:**
CustomerTypes table
Customers table (has a foreign key CustomerType). A customer can only have one customer type.
CustomersCollection table (contains many customerIds)

The primary SELECT of the query will be on CustomerTypes. I will be selecting two columns: CustomerTypeName and CountInCollection

**The CustomerCount column in my query needs to show something like the following:**
[Total # of Customers in CustomerType that are in Customer Collection] Of [Total # of Customers in CustomerType]

How can I get the proper customer count of the CustomerType that is part of the collection?

Example:

- Customer1, Customer2, and Customer3 are all of CustomerTypeA.
- CustomerCollection1 has customers Customer1 and Customer2 in it. The CountInCollection column for the CustomerTypeA record should show '2 of 3'.

[image]

Here is how I am able to get each count in separate queries:

```
-- Total customers in customer collection of customer type
SELECT COUNT(c.Id)
FROM Customer c
INNER JOIN CustomerCollection cc ON c.Id = cc.CustomerId
WHERE cc.CollectionId = 1019 AND c.CustomerTypeId=1000

-- Total customers in customer type
SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM
Customer WHERE CustomerTypeId=1000
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results in tabular format would really help convey what you want to do.

Comment: @TabAlleman I am not saying what I need. I am asking how to go about selecting a 'count of count' column in sql server. This post could definitely help others because my example is well explained.

Comment: I would disagree that your example is well explained. On the contrary it lacks enough details for anybody to provide an answer. I suspect the code for this is not that complicated but with no details to work with it is anybody's guess what you are trying to do here. I have read this question several times and it just isn't clear. This would be a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `SQL 2008`, I would take advantage of [Common Table Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx), aka CTEs, to assemble the data.

First, we'll need some test data.  NOTE:  I've thrown in some 'outliers' so that you can see where this kind of logic can bite you later.

```
DECLARE @CustomerTypes TABLE
    (
    CustomerTypeID INT,
    [Customer Type] VARCHAR(100)
    )

INSERT INTO @CustomerTypes
    SELECT 1, 'TypeA'
    UNION SELECT 2, 'TypeB'
    UNION SELECT 3, 'TypeC'  --NOTE: An outlier (not in customers-collection)
    UNION SELECT 4, 'TypeD'  --NOTE: An outlier (not in customers)

DECLARE @Customers TABLE
    (
    CustomerID INT,
    CustomerTypeID INT
    )

INSERT INTO @Customers
    SELECT 1, 1
    UNION SELECT 2, 1
    UNION SELECT 3, 1
    UNION SELECT 4, 2
    UNION SELECT 5, 2
    UNION SELECT 6, 2
    UNION SELECT 7, 3  

DECLARE @CustomersCollection TABLE
    (
    CollectionID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    CustomerID INT
    )

INSERT INTO @CustomersCollection
    (CustomerID)
    SELECT TOP 2  --INSERT 2 of 3
        CustomerID FROM @Customers WHERE CustomerTypeID = 1  --TypeA

INSERT INTO @CustomersCollection
    (CustomerID)
    SELECT TOP 1  --INSERT 1 of 3
        CustomerID FROM @Customers WHERE CustomerTypeID = 2  --TypeB
```

Second, assemble the CTE data, and generate your output

```
;WITH CTE_COUNT_TYPE(CustomerTypeID, TypeCount)
AS
(
    SELECT CustomerTypeID, COUNT(1)
    FROM @Customers
    GROUP BY CustomerTypeID
)
--SELECT * FROM CTE_COUNT_TYPE  --DEBUG
,
CTE_COUNT_COLLECTION(CustomerTypeID, CollectionCount)
AS
(
    SELECT CustomerTypeID, COUNT(1)
    FROM @CustomersCollection CC
        INNER JOIN @Customers C 
            ON CC.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
    GROUP BY CustomerTypeID
)
--SELECT * FROM CTE_COUNT_COLLECTION  --DEBUG
SELECT [Customer Type],
    --CONVERT is necessary to combine INT data type (i.e. Count) and VARCHAR data type (i.e. 'as')
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), COALESCE(CCC.CollectionCount, 0)) + 
        ' of ' + 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), COALESCE(CCT.TypeCount, 0)) As [Count in Collection]

    FROM @CustomerTypes CT
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @Customers C  --Left outer join assists in outliers
        ON CT.CustomerTypeID = C.CustomerTypeID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE_COUNT_TYPE CCT  --Left outer join assists in outliers
        ON CCT.CustomerTypeID = CT.CustomerTypeID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE_COUNT_COLLECTION CCC  --Left outer join assists in outliers
        ON CCC.CustomerTypeID = CT.CustomerTypeID
    GROUP BY CT.[Customer Type]
        , CCC.CollectionCount
        , CCT.TypeCount
```

Comment: thank you very much for the in depth response. I am currently reading through it now. Can you please see the 2 queries at the bottom of my updated post to make sure you fully understood my question. I apologize that I didn't have those queries in there to begin with.

Comment: No problem.  As for your two queries, why do you include "cc.CollectionId = 1019" in the where clause?

Comment: The primary key on my page is CustomerCollectionId which gets passed in as a param to the query. And as you already know: Customers are what gets added to a Customer Collection. But on the page for an individual CustomerCollection I want to list the distinct CustomerTypes and in the Count Column show how many Customers in the CustomerType are actually part of the CustomerCollection. CustomerCollection is a join table with two keys CollectionId and CustomerId. In other words for CollectionId 1019 I am listing the distinct CustomerTypes based on the Customers added to the CustomerCollection.

Comment: Additionally, it seems like you somehow understood what I needed because after applying your code I am so close. I keep getting extra rows though. Maybe it is because I am using DISTINCT instead of GROUP BY

Comment: I am starting to figure out what my problem is with the multiple rows. if the customers from the same CustomerType are part of different CustomerCollections the CTE_COUNT_COLLECTION CTE is returning multiple rows for each. i.e. Collection1, CustomerTypeA, 3 and Collection2, CustomerTypeA, 15 when really I only want the row with 3. I believe i just need to add an additional filter in the join to filter down by CollectionId which is the param passed in. Make sense? I needed to add an extra column to the CCC CTE to select the CustomerCollectionId also.

Answer (score 1):

Hope so i get the question-

```
select
    ct.CustomerTypeName as [Customer Type],
    convert(varchar(30),count(cc.CollectionId)) + ' of ' + convert(varchar(30), count(c.CustomerId)) as [Count in Collection]
from
    @Customer c
    inner join @CustomerType ct on ct.CustomerTypeId = c.CustomerTypeId
    left join @CustomerCollection cc on cc.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
group by
    CustomerTypeName
```

Data script-

```
declare @customerType table (CustomerTypeId int, CustomerTypeName varchar(100))
insert into @customerType (CustomerTypeId, CustomerTypeName)
select 30, 'TypeA'
union
select 40, 'TypeB'

declare @customer table (CustomerId int, CustomerTypeId int)
insert into @customer (CustomerId, CustomerTypeId)
select 1, 30
union
select 2, 30
union
select 3, 30
union
select 4, 40
union
select 5, 40
union
select 6, 40

declare @customercollection table (CollectionId int, CustomerId int)
insert into @customercollection (CollectionId, CustomerId)
select 100, 1
union
select 200, 2
union
select 300, 5
```